# what should i use instead of 'text-justify' in bootstrap?

Tags: text-alignment, statistics-bootstrap

guys as we know that bootstrap 5 removed the "text-justify" class now I don't know that what should I use instead of text-justify in bootstrap.

And I don't know why they dropped #29679.( "text-justify" class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bootstrap 5 Documentation they added a note:-

---

> Note that we don’t provide utility classes for justified text. While
> aesthetically, the justified text might look more appealing, it does make
> word-spacing was more random and therefore harder to read.

I don't find any built-in class for this, further, you can check from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/

Hence, you can use custom class with `.custom-class { text-align: justify }`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 5, `text-alignment` classes are part of **Bootstrap utilities**, which can be extended using **Utilities API**.

By default, Bootstrap 5 generates the following classes: `text-start`, `text-center`, `text-end` (*their responsive classes are also available*).

We can generate the `text-justify` class by adding an additional value to the `text-align` utilities:

```scss
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "text-align": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "text-align"),
      (
        values: map-merge(
          map-get(map-get($utilities, "text-align"), "values"),
          (justify: justify),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

CSS Output:

```css
.text-justify {
  text-align: justify !important;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .text-sm-justify {
    text-align: justify !important;
  }
}

// .text-md-justify ...
// .text-lg-justify ...

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .text-xl-justify {
    text-align: justify !important;
  }
}
```

Full SCSS code:

```scss
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// extend `text-align` utility
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "text-align": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "text-align"),
      (
        values: map-merge(
          map-get(map-get($utilities, "text-align"), "values"),
          (justify: justify),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);

// include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

DEMO:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-5-qjdfsx?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Further resources:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#using-the-api
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/#modify-utilities