# Bootstrap5: How to text-justify in lg and text-center in sm?

Tags: text, bootstrap-5, text-alignment

I'm trying to get paragraphs to be justified on desktop and left-aligned on mobile.

I tried the following:

```
<p class="text-start text-lg-justify">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

but it doesn't work as intended.

The following makes the paragraph justified for both desktop and mobile,

```
<p class="text-justify">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

But that's not what I want.

I also tried:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-lg-between">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
</div>
```

but it doesn't work as intended either. It does this [weird paragraph splitting in half](https://lahyte.com/failedjustification#About%20me).

I'm using [bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: As far as i know, `text-justify` is removed from bootstrap 5. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/29793. doc v5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment. So you have to make a class yourself

Comment: I've posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908913/what-should-i-use-instead-of-text-justify-in-bootstrap/77073694#77073694

Answer (score 0):

Please note what the docs say about justified text:

> we don’t provide utility classes for justified text. While, aesthetically, justified text might look more appealing, it does make word-spacing more random and therefore harder to read.
>
> -- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment

**Meaning fully justified on both sides* `|::.:|`

You can have left or right *aligned* text, a.k.a. left or right justified. `|:::.` or `.:::|`

The proper way to have text center-aligned in smaller viewports then left-aligned in  large and above (assuming LTR text-direction) is with `class="text-center text-lg-start"`, as demonstrated below:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">

      <p class="text-center text-lg-start">
        Center aligned text on all viewport sizes. Then, start aligned text on viewports sized LG (large) or wider.
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```